# calender.getTimeInMillis() not setting properly

Tags: android

```
Date dat = new Date();

Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();
cal_alarm.setTime(dat);
cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hrs);// set the alarm time
cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
cal_alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
if (cal_alarm.before(cal_now)) {// if its in the past increment
    cal_alarm.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, AlarmReceiver.class);
// intent.putExtra("Reminder to Take Photo", "Pixitch!");
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 192837, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
// Get the AlarmManager service
Long tmemills = cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis();

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, tmemills,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
```

Passing Values Details is

Current time is: 16:07
hrs=16
min=10

but

`tmemills` is coming 1377772800393

I am not able to find where the problem is 
because I am beginner for Android.
please help me

Comment: what is wrong with 1377772800393?

Comment: From 16:07 to 16:10 difference is around 180000 milliseconds but it is showing 1377772800393

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16220883/1777090 check it

Comment: My problem is alarm not popping up on 16:10

Comment: @Mysstic Magic I  reset MILLISECOND as 0 but still same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this

```
long tmemills = cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis() - cal_now.getTimeInMillis();
```

and this

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,tmemills +    System.currentTimeMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
```

Answer (score 0):

`cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis()` gives you the milliseconds since 1/1/1970 midnight. It is not the difference between your two dates.

to get the difference, subtract `cal_now.getTimeInMillis()` like this:

```
long tmemills = cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis() - cal_now.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: Ever heard about Java operators: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

Comment: Thank you @Henry value is comming perfect but alaram is running immidiatly... please any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the difference between two times you can use this ::

`Date date1 = cal.getTime();
                String endTime = "2013/29/08 18:59:59";
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyy/dd/MM HH:mm:ss");
Date dtEndTime = dateFormat.parse(endTime);
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###");
long diff = dtEndTime.getTime() - date1.getTime();`

the **diff** will give you the difference in millisecs.

Also the value cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis() will give u the value of the date in milliseconds, it will not give the difference of two dates.

Comment: Dear @Ritaban from long tmemills = cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis()-cal_now.getTimeInMillis(); value is coming correct but alaram manager is opening immidiatly :(

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code for creating somewhat like an alarm..hope it helps.`public class AlarmManagerActivity extends Activity {
    PendingIntent pi;
    BroadcastReceiver br;
    AlarmManager am;
    final static private long ONE_SECOND = 1000;
    final static private long Five_SECONDS = ONE_SECOND * 5;

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setup();
    findViewById(R.id.tv).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             am.set( AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 
                     Five_SECONDS, pi );
        }       });     

}    
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
       am.cancel(pi);
       unregisterReceiver(br);
       super.onDestroy();
}    
private void setup() {
    br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
           @Override
           public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
                  Toast.makeText(c, "Rise and Shine!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
           };
    registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("abc") );
    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("abc"),
```

0 );
        am = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));  }}`